# Problem with XGBoost parameter "eval_metric"

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I tried to use the `eval_metric` argument in XGBoost but got this error:

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eval_metric'
```

Here is my code:

```
eval_metric = ["error", "logloss",]

classifier_0=XGBClassifier(objective=objective,booster="gbtree",eval_metric=eval_metric,subsample=0.8,colsample_bytree=1,random_state=1,use_label_encoder=False)

# Fit Model
eval_set = [(X_train, y_train),( X_test, y_test)]
classifier_1.fit(X_train,y_train,eval_metric=eval_metric_list,eval_set=eval_set,verbose=False)
```

```
TypeError: 2 different `eval_metric` are provided.  Use the one in constructor or `set_params` instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. It seems that the "eval_metric" now needs to be defined when initially defining the model, rather than at the time of fitting.

```
model=xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100, eval_metric='rmse')
model.fit(X_train,y_train, early_stopping_rounds=10, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], verbose=False)
```

Though I believe `early_stopping_rounds` in `fit` method is also deprecated, but that is only a warning as of now.